# WPF - How to get height of each row in DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that has TextWrapping enabled in cells. Meaning that rows don't have same height. My question is how do I loop through rows and get whats the height of each one?
How the DataGrid looks like:
[image]

Here is the datagrid code:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Article> persons = new ObservableCollection<Article>();

for(int i = 0; i < 35; i++)
{
    persons.Add(new Article("Restless legs syndrome and tis correlation with other sleep problems in the general adult population of Japan",
                         "Minori Enomoto, Lan Li, Sayaka Aritake, Yukihiro Nagase, Tatsuhiko Kaji, Hirokuni Tagaya, Masato Matsuura, Yoshitaka Kaneita, Takashi Ohida, Makoto Uchiyama",
                         "Sleep and Biological Rhythms",
                         4));
}

dgMain.ItemsSource = persons;
```

Here is how I counted it:

```
        private void btnTest_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int k = 0;
        var rows = GetDataGridRows(dgMain);

        foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
        {
            var rowHeight = r?.ActualHeight;
            k++;
        }

        MessageBox.Show(k.ToString());
    }
```

And here is the Article class:

```
    public class Article
{
    private string _title;
    public string Title
    {
        get { return this._title; }
        set { this._title = value; }
    }

    private string _authors;
    public string Authors
    {
        get { return this._authors; }
        set { this._authors = value; }
    }

    private string _journal;
    public string Journal
    {
        get { return this._journal; }
        set { this._journal = value; }
    }

    private int _year;
    public int Year
    {
        get { return this._year; }
        set { this._year = value; }
    }

    public Article(string Title, string Authors, string Journal, int Year)
    {
        this._title = Title;
        this._authors = Authors;
        this._journal = Journal;
        this._year = Year;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
var rows = GetDataGridRows(datagrid);

foreach (DataGridRow r in rows)
 {
       var rowHeight = r?.ActualHeight;
 }
  public IEnumerable<DataGridRow> GetDataGridRows(System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid grid)
        {
            var itemsSource = grid.ItemsSource as IEnumerable;
            if (null == itemsSource) yield return null;
            foreach (var item in itemsSource)
            {
                var row = grid.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as DataGridRow;
                if (null != row) yield return row;
            }
        }
```

**Xaml**

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" >
        <Button Click="Button_Click" Height="39" Width="40"></Button>
        <DataGrid x:Name="dgMain" AutoGenerateColumns="True"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" >

        </DataGrid>

    </StackPanel>
```

[image: ss its working]

Comment: I tried to test it with Messagebox -  MessageBox.Show(rowHeight.ToString()); and it displayes "NaN" for each row. Do I need to cast rowHeight into different type before I try to display it via string?

Comment: @JohnDoe Hi jhon can u check with `ActualHeight` once

Comment: @JohnDoe anytime.

Comment: Now that I tested this further it works for small records but turns out to be unusable with many records. It seems this only works on the rows that are visible on the screen, I used a simple test to count the rows accessed by the loop and even though my DataGrid had 35 rows on one of my tests it counted only 8 when I reduced window size. Is there any way to achieve the same but to access all rows whether or not they are visible on the screen?

Comment: @JohnDoe can you post the code and data as example i will check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192218/discussion-between-avinash-reddy-and-john-doe).

Comment: I edited my original post to include some code samples

Comment: Hmm, for some odd reason it doesn't work for me. Here is my whole sample project, can you test it on this too?[Download Project](https://www.mediafire.com/file/gx5n17ohja64p3z/ControlTemplateDemo.rar/file)

Comment: Sure give me some time

Comment: @JohnDoe i checked its your Style which is casuing issue remove them or edit them properly it will work

Comment: Ok, I solved it. It wasn't the style that was causing the problem, but rather that I had my DataGrid in <Grid> panel. I put it in <StackPanel> and now it works perfectly. Not sure why <Grid> was causing problems though. Thanks a lot for your time and help!